# Count letter frequency in word list, excluding duplicates in the same word

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to find the most frequent letter in a list of words. I'm struggling with the algorithm because I need to count the letter frequency in a word only once skipping duplicates, so I need help finding a way to count the frequency of the letters in the entire list with only one occurrence per word, ignoring the second occurrence.

For example if i have:

```
words = ["tree", "bone", "indigo", "developer"]
```

The frequency will be:

```
letters={a:0, b:1, c:0, d:2, e:3, f:0, g:1, h:0, i:1, j:0, k:0, l:1, m:0, n:2, o:3, p:1, q:0, r:2, s:0, t:1, u:0, v:1, w:0, x:0, y:0, z:0}
```

As you can see from the letters dictionary: 'e' is 3 and not 5 because if 'e' repeats more than once in the same word it should be ignored.

This is the algorithm that I came up with, it's implemented in Python:

```
for word in words:
    count=0;

    for letter in word:
        if(letter.isalpha()):
            if((letters[letter.lower()] > 0  && count == 0) ||
               (letters[letter.lower()] == 0 && count == 0)):

                    letters[letter.lower()]+=1
                    count=1

            elif(letters[letter.lower()]==0 && count==1):   
                letters[letter.lower()]+=1
```

But it still requires work and I can't think about anything else, I'd be glad to anyone who will help me to think about a working solution.

Comment: I would describe the requirement as counting "the number of words which include each letter".

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486462/counting-letter-frequency-with-a-dict

Comment: @Stobor: Yes, and your description of the requirement also hints at a much simpler solution: Just iterate over the entire alphabet, and for each letter count how many words contain that letter.

Comment: @mbj Yep - that's the basis for my solution below. :) It's simpler, but it's a little bit slower than the solutions here, mostly because it has to try all the letters which are not in the words, as well as the ones which are...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A variation on @Primusa answer without using update:

```
from collections import Counter

words = ["tree", "bone", "indigo", "developer"]
counts = Counter(c for word in words for c in set(word.lower()) if c.isalpha())
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'e': 3, 'o': 3, 'r': 2, 'd': 2, 'n': 2, 'p': 1, 'i': 1, 'b': 1, 'v': 1, 'g': 1, 'l': 1, 't': 1})
```

Basically convert each word to a set and then iterate over each set.

Answer (score 19):

Create a counter object and then update it with sets for each word:

```
from collections import Counter

wordlist = ["tree","bone","indigo","developer"]

c = Counter()
for word in wordlist:
    c.update(set(word.lower()))

print(c)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'e': 3, 'o': 3, 'r': 2, 'n': 2, 'd': 2, 't': 1, 'b': 1, 'i': 1, 'g': 1, 'v': 1, 'p': 1, 'l': 1})
```

Note that although letters that weren't present in `wordlist` aren't present in in the `Counter`, this is fine because a `Counter` behaves like a `defaultdict(int)`, so accessing a value not present automatically returns a default value of 0.

Comment: It would be helpful to compare the time complexity of this solution to the one provided by OP

Comment: @JordanSinger I think they're the same time complexity, both solutions iterate over every character in every word; mine just screens for duplicates using a `set`

Comment: Right, I suggested that because OP was interested in efficiency.

Comment: I would rather `c.update(filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), set(word.lower()))` or something like that

Comment: @WalterTross the question states that the input is a list of words so I didn't consider punctuation or spaces, but did consider capital letters

Comment: true, but the code by the OP contains `if(letter.isalpha()):`

Answer (score 16):

One without Counter

```
words=["tree","bone","indigo","developer"]
d={}
for word in words:         # iterate over words
    for i in set(word):    # to remove the duplication of characters within word
        d[i]=d.get(i,0)+1
```

Output

```
{'b': 1,
 'd': 2,
 'e': 3,
 'g': 1,
 'i': 1,
 'l': 1,
 'n': 2,
 'o': 3,
 'p': 1,
 'r': 2,
 't': 1,
 'v': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your effort. This might be useful to people who want to implement the algorithm on their own.

Answer (score 12):

Comparing speed of the solutions presented so far:

```
def f1(words):
    c = Counter()
    for word in words:
        c.update(set(word.lower()))
    return c

def f2(words):
    return Counter(
        c
        for word in words
        for c in set(word.lower()))

def f3(words):
    d = {}
    for word in words:
        for i in set(word.lower()):
            d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1
    return d
```

My timing function (using different sizes for the list of words):

```
word_list = [
    'tree', 'bone', 'indigo', 'developer', 'python',
    'language', 'timeit', 'xerox', 'printer', 'offset',
]

for exp in range(5):
    words = word_list * 10**exp

    result_list = []
    for i in range(1, 4):
        t = timeit.timeit(
            'f(words)',
            'from __main__ import words,  f{} as f'.format(i),
            number=100)
        result_list.append((i, t))

    print('{:10,d} words | {}'.format(
        len(words),
        ' | '.join(
            'f{} {:8.4f} sec'.format(i, t) for i, t in result_list)))
```

The results:

```
        10 words | f1   0.0028 sec | f2   0.0012 sec | f3   0.0011 sec
       100 words | f1   0.0245 sec | f2   0.0082 sec | f3   0.0113 sec
     1,000 words | f1   0.2450 sec | f2   0.0812 sec | f3   0.1134 sec
    10,000 words | f1   2.4601 sec | f2   0.8113 sec | f3   1.1335 sec
   100,000 words | f1  24.4195 sec | f2   8.1828 sec | f3  11.2167 sec
```

The `Counter` with list comprehension (here as `f2()`) seems to be the fastest. Using `counter.update()` seems to be a slow point (here as `f1()`).

Comment: @Primusa ups, my bad. I updated with new results, but the conclusion is the same...

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions are good, but they specifically don't include the letters with zero frequency. Here's an approach which does, but is approximately 2-3 times slower than the others.

```
import string
counts = {c: len([w for w in words if c in w.lower()]) for c in string.ascii_lowercase}
```

which produces a dict like this:

```
{'a': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 4, 'e': 7, 'f': 2, 'g': 2, 'h': 3, 'i': 7, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 4, 'm': 5, 'n': 4, 'o': 4, 'p': 1, 'q': 0, 'r': 5, 's': 3, 't': 3, 'u': 2, 'v': 0, 'w': 3, 'x': 0, 'y': 2, 'z': 1}
```

Here's my update of Ralf's timings:

```
        10 words | f1   0.0004 sec | f2   0.0004 sec | f3   0.0003 sec | f4   0.0010 sec
       100 words | f1   0.0019 sec | f2   0.0014 sec | f3   0.0013 sec | f4   0.0034 sec
     1,000 words | f1   0.0180 sec | f2   0.0118 sec | f3   0.0140 sec | f4   0.0298 sec
    10,000 words | f1   0.1960 sec | f2   0.1278 sec | f3   0.1542 sec | f4   0.2648 sec
   100,000 words | f1   2.0859 sec | f2   1.3971 sec | f3   1.6815 sec | f4   3.5196 sec
```

based on the following code and the word list from https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/

```
import string
import timeit
import random
from collections import Counter

def f1(words):
    c = Counter()
    for word in words:
        c.update(set(word.lower()))
    return c

def f2(words):
    return Counter(
        c
        for word in words
        for c in set(word.lower()))

def f3(words):
    d = {}
    for word in words:
        for i in set(word.lower()):
            d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1
    return d


def f4(words):
    d = {c: len([w for w in words if c in w.lower()]) for c in string.ascii_lowercase} 
    return d


with open('words.txt') as word_file:
    valid_words = set(word_file.read().split())

for exp in range(5):

    result_list = []
    for i in range(1, 5):
        t = timeit.timeit(
            'f(words)',
            'from __main__ import f{} as f, valid_words, exp; import random; words = random.sample(valid_words, 10**exp)'.format(i),
            number=100)
        result_list.append((i, t))

    print('{:10,d} words | {}'.format(
        len(words),
        ' | '.join(
            'f{} {:8.4f} sec'.format(i, t) for i, t in result_list)))

print(f4(random.sample(valid_words, 10000)))
print(f4(random.sample(valid_words, 1000)))
print(f4(random.sample(valid_words, 100)))
print(f4(random.sample(valid_words, 10)))
```

Comment: But this is ASCII only -- in this day and age?

Comment: I would replace `len([w for w in words if c in w.lower()])` with `sum(c in w.lower() for w in words)`. Should be a bit faster. Thanks for the timings btw. +1

Comment: It seems that yours is actually faster. Anyway. +1

Comment: @JanneKarila - I used that as the reference list as that's what the question asked for. The algorithm doesn't change, only the list of what characters are considered interesting. I agree that ascii-letters-only is an arbitrary limitation these days.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a dictionary comprehension:

```
import string
print({k:max(i.count(k) for i in words) for k in string.ascii_lowercase})
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit too late to the party, but here you go:

```
freq = {k: sum(k in word for word in words) for k in set(''.join(words))}
```

which returns:

```
{'i': 1, 'v': 1, 'p': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 3, 'g': 1, 't': 1, 'n': 2, 'd': 2, 'o': 3, 'l': 1, 'r': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter  
import string  

words=["tree","bone","indigo","developer"]  
y=Counter(string.ascii_lowercase)  
new_dict=dict(y) 

for k in new_dict:  
    new_dict[k]=0  
trial = 0  
while len(words) > trial:  
    for let in set(words[trial]):    
        if let in new_dict:  
            new_dict[str(let)]=new_dict[str(let)]+1  

    trial = trial +1  
print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
import itertools
import string


def main():
    words = ["tree", "bone", "indigo", "developer"]
    no_repeated_letters = (set(word) for word in words)
    letter_stream = itertools.chain.from_iterable(no_repeated_letters)
    counter = collections.Counter(letter_stream)
    # set zeros for unseen letters, to match poster's answer.
    for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
        if letter not in counter:
            counter[letter] = 0
    # print result.
    for key in sorted(counter):
        print(key, counter[key])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```