# Follow up on dictionary in for loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I was going through the code on this question for the second answer...
[counting letter frequency with a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46486462/17598046)

```
word_list=['abc','az','ed']

def count_letter_frequency(word_list):
  letter_frequency={}
  for word in word_list:
    for letter in word:
      keys=letter_frequency.keys()
      if letter in keys:
          letter_frequency[letter]+=1
      else:
          letter_frequency[letter]=1
  return letter_frequency
```

I don't understand how `keys = letter_frequency.keys()` connects to the rest of the problem.

I tried playing around with the code. I understand it as follows:

```
word_list=['abc','az','ed']

def count_letter_frequency(word_list):  #function name and input

  letter_frequency={}                   #empty dictionary
  for word in word_list:                #go through word_list for each item, the       
                                          first being 'abc'
    for letter in word:                 #from 'abc', loop through each letter...'a', 
                                            'b', 'c'
      keys=letter_frequency.keys()      # where I'm stuck. i read it as our empty dictionary, 
                                          letter_fequency, plus keys(), together defined by the 
                                           variable 'keys'.  make keys out of the letters in
                                           letter_frequency (then count them using the next if/else 
                                           statement)
      if letter in keys:                # how can a letter be in keys?  there isn't anything in 
                                          letter_frequency either, is there?
          letter_frequency[letter]+=1
      else:
          letter_frequency[letter]=1
  return letter_frequency
```

Comment: It's empty for the first word, then it's not empty for the subsequent ones.

Comment: @Jason: Continue reading the code after `if letter in keys:`, those are the most important lines according to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

The condition on `if letter in keys`, appart from being inefficient and overly complex, is meant to determine if the letter should add one to the existing entry in the dictionary or add a new entry for the first occurrence of each letter.  Checking `if letter in letter_frequency` would have done the same thing.

A simpler and more efficient approach would be to let the dictionary indexing work for us (as opposed to a sequential search in keys):

```
word_list=['abc','az','ed']

letter_frequency = dict()
for word in word_list:
    for letter in word:
        letter_frequency[letter] = letter_frequency.get(letter,0) + 1
        
print(letter_frequency)
{'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'z': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1}
```

Comment: This is my preferred approach but it's worth mentioning that *defaultdict* can also be used for this. collections.Counter could also be used

Comment: Indeed, but the OP was originally attempting to do this without the Counter class and I assumed that using another class in the collections library wouldn't be an option either.

Comment: Not criticising your answer by any means. Just suggesting that it's worth mentioning other options for achieving OP's ultimate objective. Doing it the way you suggest means there's no need to import anything which is something that many would approve of

Comment: Hey there... About [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75228385/12671057): I might've been misguided by the knowledge that it does use additional space. I guess `__setitem__` *could* indeed reuse the space it already has. It just doesn't (as far as I know) and I suspect there's good reason it doesn't (like wanting to "make room" for the exact number of elements beforehand, especially when the target slice ends before the list ends, so that a suffix needs to be shifted appropriately).

Comment: @Alain T. and Pingu and Kelly Bundy  Thank you for your feedback and clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
letter_frequency={}
```

is an empty dictionary.

We then look at each word, one letter at a time.

```
for letter in word:
```

We find the keys, which is initially empty:

```
  keys=letter_frequency.keys()
```

We then consider the current letter:

```
  if letter in keys:
      letter_frequency[letter]+=1
  else:
      letter_frequency[letter]=1
```

First time round, `letter` isn't there, since `keys` is empty, so we use the `else` to add the letter, with a count of one.

```
letter_frequency[letter]=1
```

When we look at the next letter, the previous letter is in the keys.

Answer (score 0):

In your above code, `keys = letter_frequency.keys()` is used to get the list of keys present in the dictionary such as ['a','b','c']. This is to check whether the key is already present in the dictionary or not.

In my opinion, one should use word_list`.get()` function of dictionary to check the availability of a character in a dictionary.

**Refer the below code for clarification.**

```
def countLetterFrequency(word_list):
    letter_frequency = {}

    for word in word_list:
        for ch in word:
            # use .get() function instead of .keys() to check the presence of character in dictionary.
            if not letter_frequency.get(ch, False):
                letter_frequency[ch] = 1
            else:
                letter_frequency[ch] += 1

    return letter_frequency


word_list = ['abc', 'az', 'ed']
print(countLetterFrequency(word_list))
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'z': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1}
```

***Note:*** `.get()` function takes the `character in first argument` which needs to be checked in the dictionary and in `second argument takes the default` output which needs to be return when the key is not present.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration there will be nothing in letter_frequency, therefore the else condition of `if letter in keys` triggers. In the line `letter_frequency[letter]=1`, just above the return, the current `letter` will be used as a new key for the empty dict and its value will be set to 1.

Then, in the next iteration of the inner for loop, `keys=letter_frequency.keys()` will not be empty anymore.